# Failed to init angularjs, included ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not sure why I coulnd't run angularjs. I've created a repo here https://github.com/eldyvoon/temp/blob/master/app/index.html

Am I doing anything wrong? I've included angulajs, put `ng-app` and `ng-controller`, but the $scope.test doesn't work..

Comment: you forgot to include ng-app in the markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your sample you didn't declare an ng-app

try add it in the body tag of you'r index html

```
 <body ng-app="main">
```

hope this helps